# How to find JSON object contains Object or Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am working Angular js project, I am getting form server response is JSON Object. That JSON Object contains nested Objects and Arrays. for every time i need write lot coding getting the value of key

Ex:

```
{
    "mapData": {
        "data": [
            {
                "key": "name",
                "value": "abc"
            },
            {
                "key": "name",
                "value": "bcd"
            },
            {
                "key": "name",
                "value": "vbc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

what i was tried example is so many times, it is not related above example.

```
for(var key in object) {
    if(key=="Id"){
         Id= object[key].fieldValue;
        secondData.forEach(function(item){
            for(var innerItem in item){
            if(innerItem =="Id"){
                if(Id==item[innerItem].fieldValue){
                        FinalData.push(item);
                        }
                     }
        }
    }); 
 }
}
```

Is there any way generic way Instead of writing every time for for loop and For Each loop.
could you please suggest any things

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: just one thing, JSON is not an object, it's text. it's the serielized form of the object. there is not such a thing "JSON Object"

Comment: You need to share your code as @Shubh said but whatever you post I think the answer will be http://underscorejs.org/ :)

Comment: We don't know, response object contain what structure, It may be Array or Object, As per that only, we need to get key Value Right. In the Above example i need get Key is Name and i want value of that key. how can i achieve that, Could you any please give me any solution for this Problem @Shubh

Comment: This is one Example i am writing code every time in my project:

`for(var key in object) {
 if(key=="Id"){
      Id= object[key].fieldValue;
  secondData.forEach(function(item){
   for(var innerItem in item){
   if(innerItem =="Id"){
    if(Id==item[innerItem].fieldValue){
         FinalData.push(item);
         }
      }
  }
 }); 
 }
}`

Comment: Don't dump code in comment blocks. Update the question so it can be formatted and read

Comment: Angular has both [isArray()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray) and [isObject()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isObject) methods.

Answer (score 0):

`mapData.data[i].key` will return your key value. i is index of your data array you can easily iterate data by

```
for(var i =0;i<mapData.data.length;i++){}
```